# Troca de servidor de hospedagem para sites

Tags: hospedagem

Um colega meu quer passar o site dele para o servidor que hospedo os meus sites. O que eu gostaria de saber é oq realmente eu preciso para que essa troca seja feita? A agência que detém o site, domínio e hospedagem dele deve alterar o DNS para o meu servidor, correto? Se sim, não corre-se o risco de a qualquer momento eles trocarem esse dns causando uma queda no site? O que fazer para que isso não ocorra? Além do mais, meu colega possui os e-mails pelo gsuite, então, uma troca de domínio não é viável pois ele possui muitos clientes. Eu precisaria que tanto o domínio quanto a hospedagem ficassem sob minha responsabilidade e não que a outra empresa tivesse qualquer tipo de acesso ou vínculo após a troca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (sic) oq realmente eu preciso para que essa troca seja feita?
>   A agência que detém o site, domínio e hospedagem dele deve alterar o DNS para o meu servidor, correto?

Deve sim apontar o domínio para seu servidor.

> não corre-se o risco de a qualquer momento eles trocarem esse dns causando uma queda no site?

Esse é um risco praticamente "certo". Quando apontar o domínio para o seu servidor, vai ter um tempo de propagação que, normalmente, é de até 72 horas. Essa propagação vai acontecendo aos poucos e pode ser liberado antes em determinadas regiões.

> O que fazer para que isso não ocorra?

Mantenha uma réplica do site no servidor antigo e não suspenda-o até o término da propagação. Vale lembrar que o banco de dados deve ser o mesmo para ambos os servidores. Logo, se o site está no mesmo servidor (atual), o site novo deve apontar para o banco de dados do servidor antigo. Quando passar o tempo de propagação, basta migrar seu banco de dados e reconfigurar o servidor novo com esse banco de dados. Assim você só vai ficar com o site em manutenção enquanto somente estiver migrando...

> Eu precisaria que tanto o domínio quanto a hospedagem ficassem sob minha responsabilidade e não que a outra empresa tivesse qualquer tipo de acesso ou vínculo após a troca.

Basta solicitar à empresa que gerencia o domínio atualmente.